# Hiding as a Ninja Squid

Tags: splatoon-2

I'm playing as a ninja squid, but for some reason some people still see me while hiding in ink.

**Is it possible to see a ninja squid hiding with normal weapons?**

Comment: Why do you think they can see you?

Comment: mainly cause i got hit by a sniper while i spend most of my time hiding and moving using Ninja squid

Comment: If you are swimming up a wall you will still kick up ink.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ninja Squid means opponents cannot see your squid's movement or surface ripple in your own ink. However there are several things that bypass this:

- Getting hit by a weapon will give your opponent a very noticeable sound and screen effect, alerting them to your location
- Accidentally moving into enemy ink
- Any sort of effect that reveals your location, such as with a Point Sensor or Thermal Ink (indicated by a dark grey transparent squid circling around you)
- Swimming up walls (thanks @LyricsBot)
- Popping up out of the ink for any reason, such as leaping up after going up a ramp
- Your opponent just guessing and getting lucky

Comment: I'm pretty sure you leave a very faint trail as you swim. This is most noticeable on perfectly smooth, flat, inked surfaces. Good players may be able to spot you because of this.

Comment: I believe Josh is correct. Secondly, someone in a tube video asserts that you make a slight **sound**; I think that might be true also.